# How to obtain the generated by database not id column after save

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The following entity has non id column `COLUMN_NONID`. This column is populated from database sequence called in trigger(before insert on table)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="tableABC")
public class ABCClass implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="COLUMN_ID")
   private Long columnId;

   -----
   -----
   @Column(name="COLUMN_NONID")
   private Long nonIdColumn;
   ----
}
```

When I tried to insert new record in this table. The object `abcClassEnity` returned from save contain `nonIdColumn` value as `null`. This column value exists in database and it is defined as not null column. How I can retrieve this column value from save.

```java
abcClassEnity = tableABCRepository.save(abcClassEnity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Generated` annotation was designed exactly for this purpose. You can correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "COLUMN_NONID", insertable = false)
private Long nonIdColumn;
```

See the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated) for the further explanation.